# mysql concat how to put the single quotes in

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to make mysql export last day table

```
set @filepath='C:\\Db\\Dbtest.csv';
select @lastday := date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day);
SET @datanewname = '_m2_raw_Data';
SELECT @datalasttablename:=concat(@lastday,@datanewname);
SELECT @query:=CONCAT('SELECT *FROM','`',@datalasttablename,'`',' INTO OUTFILE ','''',@filepath,'''');
PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT;
```

but it can not execute as Select * from `2017-11-09_m2_raw_data` into outfile 'c:\Db\test.csv'

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: yes it show me #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''C:\Db\Dbtest.csv' at line 1

Comment: I suggest you examine the value of `@query`. It's hard to debug when you're looking at code that builds the query instead of looking at the query.

Comment: Can you `Select @query` to see what it's built and post it please?

Comment: Also consider using the QUOTE() function instead of giving yourself headaches trying to get the quotes to match. This is exactly the right time to use that function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote

Comment: Thanks reply. it shows after select @query":| SELECT *FROM`2017-11-09_m2_raw_Data` INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Db\Dbtest.csv' | and I try to execute stmt  it shows me another error is :ERROR 1086 (HY000): File 'C:DbDbtest.csv' already exists but my path is c:\\Db\\Dbtest.csv how come to be C:DbDbtest?  I found the file in my xampp\mysqdata